# How to run consecutively several .exe\.bat files in apach ANT, waiting for the end of the previous?

Tags: java, ant

How to run consecutively several .exe.bat files in apach ANT, waiting for the end of the previous?

For example:

```
<exec executable="d:/setup.exe">
            <arg line="-silent -responseFile db_install.rsp"/>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="c:\netca.bat">
            <arg line="-silent -responseFile d:/netca.rsp}"/>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="c:\dbca.bat">
            <arg line="-silent -responseFile d:/dbca.rsp"/>
        </exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant will execute each `exec` command sequentially by default.

To execute a script like a `.bat` file, you need to exec via `cmd`, just like you do to execute a script from Java, e.g.

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="d:/setup.exe"/>
    <arg value="-silent"/>
    <arg value="-responseFile"/>
    <arg value="d:/netca.rsp"/>
</exec>
```

A `.exe` file can be executed directly.

Individual `<arg>` elements (as used above) per are generally preferrable to a single arg line.